# Mongo db PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method database::selectCollection()

Tags: php, mongodb, inheritance, mongodb-query, database

I am trying to make my way through Mongo DB and PHP developing an MVC application (pardon my terminology). I am struck with the base issue of inheritance with the classes. I went through a couple of methods described in the Stack Overflow question but cannot get around this issue. 
My Mongo DB looks like

Database : Test123 
Collection : users1

*Index page* :

```
require 'libs/bootstrap.php';   
require 'libs/controller.php';  
require 'libs/view.php';        
require 'libs/model.php';       

// Libraries
require 'libs/database.php';

$app = new bootstrap();
```

My Mongo connection sits in libs/database.php

```
class database {
    public function __construct() {
            $this->connection = new MongoClient();
            $this->db = $this->connection->test123;
            }
    }// end of constructor
```

My base model class sits in libs/Model.php

```
public function __construct(database $db) {
        $this->db =$db;
    }
```

My sub model which has the login code is in models/login_model.php

```
class login_model extends Model{

    public function check($login,$password){
        $database = $this->db;  
        $collection = $database->selectCollection("user1"); // Line 9 : selecting the collection here

    }
}
```

My Controller loads the model :

```
public function loadModel($name) {
        $path = 'models/'.$name.'_model.php';
        if (file_exists($path)) {
            require $path;
            $db = new database();
            $modelName = $name.'_model';
            $this->model = new $modelName ($db);
        }
    }
```

It gives me error:
 **Fatal error: Call to undefined method database::selectCollection() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Server/models/login_model.php on line 9**

---

**What I have worked on so far to solve this**
I tried putting the error triggering line in the __construct() of my libs/database.php file and it works fine. So I understand that there is an inheritance issue where for some reason my login_model is not inheriting the mongo class. If anyone can help me fix this it is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: 1. Pass the `database` instance in to the `Model` constructor as a dependency, don't create a new connection for each model instance. 2. Catching an exception only to `die` with only its message is just silly. Let the exception go uncaught and it will stop your program anyway and give you **much more** information about what went wrong.

Comment: 3. You don't need to override a constructor if it does nothing. Just don't add a constructor to `login_model`

Comment: 4. Your `database` class doesn't have a `selectCollection` method which is the crux of your issue. You probably want `$database = $this->db->db;`

Comment: @Phil - Thanks for the helpful feedback . Can you help me giving me a brief on how will I pass the database instance into the model constructor to avoid creating new connection for each model ?

Comment: Sure, have your `Model` constructor like `public function __construct(database $db) { $this->db = $db; }` then instantiate the `database` instance and pass it in when creating models, ie `$db = new database(); ... $model = new login_model($db);`

Comment: Thanks @Phil I updated the code based on your suggestion. It still does not do the trick . Can you have a look now and tell me whats wrong in there. For your reference I have also added my controller code which loads the models based on the page requested. Appreciate your help